# How to edit JSON array before encode using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, mysqli

Here i want to edit JSON array for product image where i want to send image name (coming from database) and image path (static and not coming from databse) both in 
My json array where

image= (image path + image name)

**I am doing this way**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type='$product' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$dbdata = array();
      if ($result) 
      {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_array())  {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
        }

         echo json_encode($dbdata);
      }
```

**Output is**

```
"aprice": "90",
    "7": "85",
    "oprice": "85",
    "8": "0",
    "offer": "0",
    "9": "133259dac801eaeeb37b3876b3966ee4.jpg",
    "image": "133259dac801eaeeb37b3876b3966ee4.jpg"
```

Here i want to add image path before image name

**I tried this**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type='$product' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$dbdata = array();
      if ($result) 
      {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_array())  {
        $image="xyzabc.com/admin/upload/product_img/".$row['image'];
        $dbdata[]=$row;
        foreach($dbdata as $key => $value)
        {
          $dbdata[$key]['image'] = $image;
        }
        $mainarr = array('status' =>"200" , );
        }

         echo json_encode($dbdata);
      }
```

**Output of above code**

```
"7": "85",
    "oprice": "85",
    "8": "0",
    "offer": "0",
    "9": "133259dac801eaeeb37b3876b3966ee4.jpg",
    "image": "xyzabc.com/admin/upload/product_img/cf6e65aa87538f218c29cf3033954c31.jpg"
```

And output is not expected also image name is last product's image name.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your data before add to the array:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type='$product' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$dbdata = array();
if ($result) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array())  {
        $row['image'] = "xyzabc.com/admin/upload/product_img/".$row['image']; // <--HERE
        $dbdata[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dbdata);
}
```

Some side notes:

1. it's better to choose which columns will be sent, as you can modify the table and broke the other side. So, in this case, it's better to use `SELECT aprice, oprice, image, ... FROM Products ...`
2. You query is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Read here how to use prepared queries: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you Felippe your solution is working for me and thanks for your some side notes..and ill must go through with prepared queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion.  Use `CONCAT()` in your sql so that you can directly dump the whole result set into your `json_encode()` call.  No loop needs to be written.

Untested Code:

```
$query = "SELECT aprice,
                 oprice,
                 offer,
                 CONCAT('xyzabc.com/admin/upload/product_img/', image)
          FROM products
          WHERE product_type = ?"
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $product);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Here's a trustworthy place to read about prepared statements: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select